# Logitech Options Daemon on Catalina

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

Just installed Logitech Options on my MacOS Catalina to control a brand new MX-Keys keyboard.

The issue is that at boot, the Daemon is running (as shown in processes list monitor) but it looks like it is not, as I don't have any option available. I have to manually run and close Logitech Options app in order to have it fully working.

This is weird...

Comment: Options updated yesterday - did you get it yet? Doesn't seem to be a control panel any more & now called 'Logi Options' in Apps, v8.02.86 you can access updates from the 'More' button in the CP/app.

Comment: I am running 8.02.86. At boot, no options available. I have to manually run Logi Options app (and then close it).  Tried to contact Logitech SUpport, but they are absconding

Comment: Can't test on Catalina - working fine on Mojave. I'd say report it to Logitech… but I've never known them actually care about Mac support at all, it always seems an afterthought to them.

Comment: Thanks. Reported to them 3 days ago... Let's see what happens.

Comment: Incidentally, does it still show up as a control panel to you? I don't think I've rebooted since I installed it - have some other updates to run so going to do that now & reboot, then check again...

Comment: No, no entry in the System Preferences. Just in Applications and Library.